# Sample size and power calculations for multiple linear regression looking for an r squared increase

Tags: multiple-regression, statistical-power, r-squared

I want to perform a multiple regression, comparing a model with "traditional" risk factors, with a model that has two tested "novel" risk factors.

I'm want to make sure that the analysis is properly powered for my achieved sample size.

I am using G-Power for sample size/power calculations. There are two options for linear regression analyses: Fixed model- r squared deviation from zero; or Fixed model, r squared increase. I think I want to use the latter, r squared increase as I am examining whether the addition of the novel risk factors will increase the predictive power of the model, by comparing the adjusted r squared and residual standard error of the two models. I think this is the right approach, but there may be suggestions on that.

My specific question is, how many variables can I include in the base model (just "traditional" risk factors)? Using G power, it doesn't seem to matter how many total independent variables/ predictors I include in the model (as long as it is fewer than number in my sample size), only the number of tested variables. But if I was testing the base model itself, looking at an r squared deviation from zero, I would be limited to a set number of variables.

For example: I have n=68. At an alpha  0.05, and desired power of 80%, I could test 2 variables, looking for an r squared increase from base model,regardless of total number of predictors, in this screenshot = 6 (4 traditional, 2 novel):

[image]

But, looking at an r sqaured deviation from zero calculation, if I wanted 80% power, then I could include only 2 variables in the base model.

[image]

If I'm only interested in the R sqauared change between the two models, do I need to consider the sample size and power when deciding the number of variables in my base mode, or can I do this based on theoretical considerations only?

Comment: Why are you interested in an R-squared increase at all?  Its occurrence tells you essentially nothing.  And to what would your phrase "theoretical considerations" refer?

Comment: You should really be looking at an a priori and not post-hoc calculation. +1 to whuber, if you want to maximize R2 just throw all of the predictors you can think of in the model (it cannot go down). The only difference between the two tests you are showing, which are both on 2 df, is that the first also subtracts the non-tested predictors from the denominator. Essentially, testing 2 predictors or 2 *additional* predictors is the same minus those 'non-tested' ddf, which is a small difference compared to the 68 you have overall.

Comment: @whuber, by theoretical considerations I mean choosing variables based on previous evidence that shows they are significant predictors in the population of interest. And why not look at r squared increase?

Comment: Because R-squared is *guaranteed* not to decrease as you continue adding variables *ad infinitum.*  Consequently, an increase in R-squared tells you almost nothing. It's unclear what kind of "previous evidence" you might have in mind or what you mean by "significant predictors:" those phrases suggest you are trying to ask a question that is very different from what have articulated.

Comment: @whuber, thanks.  I mean, for example, blood pressure  and age are known risk factor for cardiovascular disease from previous studies in my population.  If I wanted to examine if an other variable (e.g. inflammation) was a predictor of cardiovascular disease, independent of age and blood pressure, how would I do that aside from looking at adjusted r squared increase. Adjusted r squared can decrease as more variables are added

Comment: Please review our threads on multiple regression: this is a basic question addressed in any multiple regression setting and can be handled with various approaches depending on the objectives of the analysis, including F-ratio tests, likelihood ratio tests, comparing AIC or BIC, cross-validation, and much more.