# Choosing number of predictor variables for regression models based on sample size and desired power

Tags: multiple-regression, statistical-power

Based on comments a previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/631856/sample-size-and-power-calculations-for-multiple-linear-regression-looking-for-an), I have changed my question.

I am wanting to see if the addition of "novel" variables to a model containing "traditional" variables improves the prediction of levels of the DV. For example, age and blood pressure are established predictors of atherosclerosis, amongst others. I include these in my base model. I then want to add kidney function and physical activity and compare the two models. I will compare the models by looking at AIC.

My question is about power, sample sizes and number of predictors. Using G power there are two options for calculating sample size in linear regression models: r squared deviation from zero, and r squared increase. I achieved a smaller sample size than planned, so now trying to calculate how many variables I can include in my models. What is the right approach here? Do I need to worry about sample size when designing models, or can I test multiple and choose the best fitting, lowest AIC, regardless of the number of variables. Which of the two options in G power is an appropriate method of seeing how many variables I can include in a model, based on desired power and sample size?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the situation, you have already gotten the sample. In this case, I would not do power analysis, but, rather, concern myself with overfitting.

To my mind, the main purpose of *a priori* sample size calculation is figuring out how big a sample you need. But your sample is determined. This then looks a lot like *post hoc* power analysis, which is frowned upon. But ... I'm curious what others say because, while you have the sample, you haven't done the analysis. So, this is really power analysis *en media res* (in the middle) and I don't know about that.

Comment: What if I reworded the question as follow: I want to calculate a sample size necessary to compare a regression model with 5 predictors to a regression model with 7 predictors (the same 5 plus an additional 2). How do I calculate this?

Comment: You would then use the 2nd option in GPower that you describe.